Convert Data from .TXT file to YAML format using Python?
I have a massive file containing data that looks like this:
    H|Column1|Column2|Column3|
    T|2022-07-01|00001|TEST 1|
    T|2022-07-01|00002|TEST 2|
    F | Record count |    2| | 

How do I create the following into YAML format via Python?
I am quite new to this, so if someone can be so kind as to provide me with an example in order to accomplish the above, that would be great thanks.
It should look like this:
H: T
Column1: 2022-07-01
Column2: 00001
Column3: TEST 1
-
 H: T
Column1: 2022-07-01
Column2: 00002
Column3: TEST 2


Please provide an example of what the output format in YAML should be.

This looks more like a character separated values (CSV) file than a text file (TXT).

Your "desired output" isn't valid YAML.

@triplee like I said, I'm very new to this and am asking the community for assistance.

You can use the csv and PyYAML libraries to import the "|"-separated values and then dump them into YAML.
The CSV readers (DictReader and reader), can use any one character as a delimiter. It could be a comma, a tab or the character your input data has, the pipe |.
The DictReader reads each row of a CSV/TSV into a dictionary object, where the keys are the column names specified in the header. There's an empty field in your input file (the | at the end) which can be deleted. There are some leading/trailing spaces in the field values which may not need to be there and those can be stripped.
With the dictionary object, the YAML can be generated. PyYAML can dump a stream of dictionaries into one YAML output. So if it's a massive file, you can read the input file, process it and stream the output to an output file line by line.
import csv
import io
import yaml


input_data = '''    H|Column1|Column2|Column3|
    T|2022-07-01|00001|TEST 1|
    T|2022-07-01|00002|TEST 2|
    F | Record count |    2| |
'''

def read_tsv(input_data):
    with io.StringIO(input_data) as f:
        cr = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='|', skipinitialspace=True)
        for row in cr:
            del row['']
            for key, value in row.items():
                row[key] = value.strip()
            yield row

print(yaml.dump_all(read_tsv(input_data), sort_keys=False))

The output looks like this:
H: T
Column1: '2022-07-01'
Column2: '00001'
Column3: TEST 1
---
H: T
Column1: '2022-07-01'
Column2: '00002'
Column3: TEST 2
---
H: F
Column1: Record count
Column2: '2'
Column3: ''



It kind of sucks that PyYAML will write the entries in alphabetical order, always. Some other YAML libraries offer more flexibility.

@tripleee when I checked help(yaml), there is a sort_keys parameter for the dump_all method

Thanks, it's been a while since I needed this information; good to see that it has finally changed!

Using native python without external libraries,
def convert_to_yaml(data):
    lines = data.strip().split('\n')
    headers = lines[0].split('|')[:-1]
    rows = [line.split('|') for line in lines[1:]]
    
    yaml_text = ""
    for row in rows:
        for i, col_name in enumerate(headers):
            yaml_text += f"{col_name}: {row[i]}\n"
        yaml_text += "-\n"
    
    return yaml_text.strip('-\n')


data = """H|Column1|Column2|Column3|
T|2022-07-01|00001|TEST 1|
T|2022-07-01|00002|TEST 2|
F | Record count |    2| |"""

print(convert_to_yaml(data))


H: T 
Column1: 2022-07-01
Column2: 00001
Column3: TEST 1
-
H: T
Column1: 2022-07-01
Column2: 00002
Column3: TEST 2
-
H: F 
Column1:  Record count 
Column2:     2
Column3:  


One of the perils of rolling your own is that your results might trigger a corner case somewhere. For example, the leading zeros are problematic; you probably want to put those inside quotes. YAML is rather unwieldy and has a lot of this type of quirks. Also, the single dash as separator is wrong (though I guess blame the OP for providing undesired desired output).

The real question is, Why yaml? Seems strange. The format he wants is inefficient. The column names are repeated n-1 times (where n is the number of lines).
I would rather use pandas to read the file and pass "|" as delimiter/separator.
Whatever he wants to achieve, I am sure converting to yaml in that format is not the best way.

@tripleee I agree that in general it is better to use a YAML library to dump files, as it checks the need for quotes (by reading back the dumped node and see if the type is still a string). But the leading zeros (multiple) are only problematic when dealing with outdated libraries, as YAML 1.2 expects 0o for octal. So at least the 00001 (without quotes) in the OP's desired output has nothing undisered about it (other things do).
